# Prey-predator dynamical system

Tags: non-linear-systems, models, complex-systems

I'm working with a prey-predator differential equation system and I have a problem with the competitive exclusion principle.

In its simplest form, this principle states that if there are 2 predators and 1 resource, one of the predators will die ([Hardin 1960](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.131.3409.1292); [Armstrong and McGehee 1980](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2460592#metadata_info_tab_contents)). This principle can be extended to the case of n predators and k resources with n> k.

In reality, this principle is often disregarded in nature and in this regard several works have been published that propose different mechanisms to explain the overcoming of the principle of competitive exclusion, for example: [Armstrong – McGehee mechanism revisited: Competitive exclusion and coexistence of nonlinear consumers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022519313002543) by Xiao Xiao and Gregor F. Fussmann.

I am trying to apply what explained in the article (I'm considering the dynamic system (nutrient-predator1-predator2) N-P1-P2):

- introducing a logistic growth in nutrients to have an oscillating solution of the N-P1 system
- calculate N1*, N2* (equilibrium solutions of the single nutrient-predator systems in the absence of the other predator, respectively in the case of the N-P1 and N-P2 systems)
- calculate < N1 > the average of the nutrients over a period of the limit cycle solution of the single N-P1 system.

For coexistence to exist, the following must apply: < N1 > > N2*> N1*.

While N2*, N1* are a function of the parameters of the problem and can be fixed in such a way that they satisfy the inequality, < N1 > is calculated numerically by integrating over the period of the limit solution of the N-P1 system and therefore it is difficult to keep under control as is calculated after the choice of parameters.

For the moment I can't get past this point, that is to find a set of parameters for which < N1 > > N2*> N1*. I'm trying to implement it numerically without success.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Links to abstract pages?

Comment: Armstrong and McGehee 1980: [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2460592#metadata_info_tab_contents)                                                                                                                            Armstrong – McGehee mechanism revisited: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022519313002543)

Comment: I'd say try imagining a concrete real scenario for N1, N2, then re-do the implementation timestep by timestep. Does each timestep make sense? Often our brain is quite sensitive at picking out a hidden nonsensical condition or loophole that's not always apparent on the math.

Comment: If you are asking me if individual N-P1 and N-P2 systems have reasonable time evolution, yes they do. The problem arises when I insert the second compartment of P because I obtain the death of one of the two P1 or P2 depending on the choice of parameters. While I would like to choose the parameters so that they both survive.